# package-install can't find icicles

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to install icicles in Emacs because I've read it makes for a more clear emacs experience. The problem is, even though I'm loading the Melpa repositories, and Checked melpa for if the package was available (it was) If I try package-install on it, it returns [no match].

I've tried package-refresh-contents to na avail. Please help with this, I could do it manually, but AUGH!

Just for context, here's the contents on my .emacs:

```
;; packages
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp")
(defun require-package (package)
    (setq-default highlight-tabs t)
      "Install given PACKAGE."
        (unless (package-installed-p package)
              (unless (assoc package package-archive-contents)
                      (package-refresh-contents))
                  (package-install package)))
(package-initialize)
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(require 'php-mode)
(eval-after-load 'php-mode
  '(require 'php-ext))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.json$" . js-mode))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("f5eb916f6bd4e743206913e6f28051249de8ccfd070eae47b5bde31ee813d55f" default))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;;
```

Thanks in advance, all help is very much appreciated

Comment: Are you seeing any packages from melpa in the `package-list-packages` output at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem by doing M-x eval-buffer on my .emacs.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then a restart of emacs would have done the same: meaning the .emacs file you posted was valid all along :) . The real issue with Icicles from MELPA is that it's not published on MELPA anymore. See the answer by Björn.

Answer (score 1):

Icicles is no longer distributed on ELPA or MELPA:

> NOTE:

> Icicles, as well as my other libraries that are on EmacsWiki, used to be obtainable also from MELPA. You may still find some of them there, but they are likely not up-to-date.

> As of 2017-10, MELPA has decided to no longer accept Lisp libraries from EmacsWiki. This includes my libraries, even though these libraries are read-only (administrator lock on the wiki pages). Too bad. This means that you must download Icicles and my other libraries only from Emacs Wiki. Sorry about that. I upload Icicles files only to the wiki.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries